# Symfony 3.4 how to set locale

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling, locale, symfony-3.4

Using symfony 3.4 I am setting the locale using an Event Listener with higher priority than `LocaleListener` as descibed in the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/translation/locale.html):

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use AppBundle\Component\Common;
use AppBundle\Entity\Client;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class EventListener
{
    private $entityManager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->entityManager !== null) {
            $client = Common::getClient($this->entityManager);
            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($client->getDefaultLocale());
        }
    }
}
```

Now to my understanding, to get the locale in a twig template, I use

```
{{ app.request.locale }}
```

which outputs the locale which I set via the EventListener (namely `en`). But I also implement the `getDisplayLocale()` method on my `Member`-object with which I log in to the page. The idea here is that without login, the default locale of the client should be used, if logged in, the locale of the member. Now the member locale is `de`.

The wired thing I do not understand now is, that the page is actually rendered in German and the symfony status bar shows german, even thought the twig template variable `{{ app.request.locale }}` shows `en`:

[image: symfony locale and app.request.locale]

Why is the variable shown in the symfony status bar and the one from `{{ app.request.locale }}` not the same? How do I set the variable that is actually used for the translation in my twig template in the EventListener?

Comment: there apparently is a place, where the locale is given to the Translator component ... (or it's not ...) I'm not quite sure right now, where though. question is, is it overridden, after it was set on the request, or set before and not updated ...

Comment: I have the following in my config.yml: framework: `translator: { fallsbacks: ['%locale%'| }` and above that I have `parameters: locale: 'de'`. I feel that this is overwriting something it shouldn't. But I don't remember changing something here, I think it's symfony default ...

Comment: wait ... do you actually have english translations for whatever you have on your page? because translation will fallback on the "default" language. and that `de_DE` display may just be a display error ... provide the translations to your script and check if that helps ... otherwise it might not actually be a problem

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The translation language taken is the one provided by the Member-Entity, not the one of the fallback. It only takes the fallback information, if no Member is logged in (then it should take the one set by the EventListener, but it doesn't for some reason). Also my main problem is, why is the `app.request.locale` in the twig template different from the locale that is actually used to translate the page? What sense does the `app.request.locale` make then??

Comment: the listener that sets the translator-locale: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/TranslatorListener.php .... maybe some weird wrong locale is used and it falls back to the default somewhere? app.request.locale does make sense, since it says what locale was provided by  the user via route or whatever.

Comment: So which variable in twig contains the locale that is actually used to translate the page?

Comment: none. when you call  the `|trans` filter on a string the `TranslatorInterface` in the container is used (see [TranslationExtension](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/TranslationExtension.php) and the used [TranslatorTrait](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Contracts/Translation/TranslatorTrait.php)) it's similar with the router, in case you're wondering.